# Dynamically render image from a table to a different location on html page

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

In the table below, I want to extract the content of the column 'Photo' for the selected row and render the image at a location on the html page. The column 'image' is a path to a jpg image.

In the example below, row 3 is selected and thus **peter.jpg** should be displayed in the box

[image]

- For the column: Photo, the path to the image folder and file is dynamically generated from a concatenation of Name in column 1 + '/assets/images/'. For example:

  **'/assets/images/' + col_1_value + '.jpg'**
- As you scroll through the table, the image in the box changes

After posting this question, I found the following script on Stackoverflow that picks up the value of a url from the table. I wish to assign that url wrapped in an  to a text area (or any other html aware container). I am trying to do this in the bold section of the code without success.

```
<script>
    (function () {
        if (window.addEventListener) {
            window.addEventListener('load', run, false);
        } else if (window.attachEvent) {
            window.attachEvent('onload', run);
        }
        function run() {
            var t = document.getElementById('table_main');
            t.onclick = function (event) {
                event = event || window.event; //IE8
                var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
                while (target && target.nodeName != 'TR') { // find TR
                    target = target.parentElement;
                }
                var cells = target.cells; //cell collection - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement
                if (!cells.length || target.parentNode.nodeName == 'THEAD') {
                    return;
                }
   
                var f2 = document.getElementById('image_url');
                **f2.value = <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename = '/assets/images/name.jpg') }}" width="16" height="16" alt="name" border="0">;**
            };
        }
    })();
</script>
```

How can I do this?
This is for a Python Flask, bootstrap project.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `img` tags to display images in your page (https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp)

```
<table id="table">
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>photo</th>
        </tr>
   <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>42</td>
            <td><img src="/assets/images/john.jpg" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Peter</td>
            <td>35</td>
            <td><img src="/assets/images/peter.jpg" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Mary</td>
            <td>54</td>
            <td><img src="/assets/images/mary.jpg" /></td>
        </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Sorry I missed out critical details. The images should be displayed in a box/div else where on the page. Moreover the image files are located in a folder and are picked up dynamically and populated in the table.